# Django-Paypal IPN 403 Error

Tags: django, paypal, http-status-code-403, paypal-ipn

I was working on the paypal ipn listener - it didn't seem to be 'hearing' the signals, although the database was updated so I know the ipn was accepted by the paypal.standard.ipn package.

Now I get a 403 error from the ipn simulator - does anyone have any idea why this would happen? When I navigate directly to the listener url there is no error.

I added @csrf_exempt to the listener, but that didn't help.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Listeners.py:

```
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from paypal.standard.ipn import signals as paypal_signals
from messaging import send
from utests.models import Test
 import logging


@csrf_exempt
@receiver(paypal_signals.payment_was_successful)
def payment_was_succesful_listener(sender, **kwargs):
     #:sender is the PayPalIPN model instance
    logging.debug("in payment successful listener")
    ... the rest of the code is commented out while I debug...


@receiver(paypal_signals.payment_was_flagged, dispatch_uid="dl-payment_was_flagged")
def payment_was_flagged_listener(sender, **kwargs):
    #:sender is the PayPalIPN model instance
    pass
```

As you can see, all that is supposed to happen is some debugging, but it doesn't get there.

Comment: Check your error logs / permissions. For some reason the script is returning 403 (Forbidden). We won't really known why as that's up to your script / environment.

Comment: @Robert is correct, without logs (and perhaps seeing the related code), this question is impossible to answer, and borders on being too localized. I'm not closing it (yet) because if improved, it could be useful to someone else, especially if you show us the relevant code.

Comment: The error logs don't show anything - the access logs just show the remote ip, url and 403. I hadn't changed any permissions before the 403 error came up, but just to be sure I double-checked all the permissions and they are fine. I'll post the logs just in case...

Comment: access log: 173.0.82.126 - - [06/Sep/2011:18:01:56 +0000] "POST /billing/something/hard/to/guess/ HTTP/1.0" 403 2488

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue again. Here is the solution in case anyone else has this problem:

The @csrf_exempt needs to be added to the django-paypal package itself.

In paypal/standard/ipn/views.py add:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

at the top, among the rest of the imports, and

```
@csrf_exempt
```

above the @require_POST above the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very late answer, but I had exactly the same problem. Turns out we hadn't turned off the apache Basic Authentication on our server (which was in place during development). PayPal can't get through that authentication layer, so gets a 403 in response. It could have been another issue, but this was certainly our problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
It turns out that in my virtualenv I **have installed** django-paypal and in my project, I had the app **paypal**.
When I add the @csrf_exempt to my app didn't work, because django always call the paypal package in my Virtualenv.
I did an pip uninstall django-paypal and everything goes well (Another solution maybe is modify the package view)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to your urls.py layout.  I was dumb enough to have a '^' regex for a default home landing page.  When I switched the ipn url to be before that statement everything worked.